# Não precisa escapar o "." num campo [...] em REGEX?

Tags: regex

Estava vendo algumas expressões regulares aqui na rede, e notei que em muitas, no campo de caracteres, o `.` não tava escapado `\.`. Assim : `[a-zA-Z0-9.]`.
Ele não precisa do caractere `\` antes, não?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não, porque não faria sentido permitir "qualquer caractere" dentro de colchetes. Considere o exemplo dado. Se o ponto dentro do colchete fosse especial, a expressão:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.]
```

seria equivalente a simplesmente:

```
.
```

(i.e. ambos casam "um caractere qualquer")

Já que não há sentido usar dessa maneira, o `.` dentro do colchete é considerado um ponto mesmo, e portanto não precisa ser "escapado".

Comment: Então se eu colocar um `+`, `{`, `$` não vai precisar do caractere `\` antes?

Comment: Não. Dentro dos colchetes, as únicas coisas que você precisaria escapar são os `[`, `]` e a `\ ` (óbvio) e em algumas circunstâncias o `^` (se for o primeiro caractere do conjunto mas não for uma negação) e o `-` (se estiver entre um caractere e outro mas não for um intervalo). [Exemplo](http://rubular.com/r/W7bQC5nDxl).

Comment: complementando, colchetes não precisam ser escapados na classe se forem os primeiros elementos (e.g. `[][0-9]+`) e hífen não precisa de escape se for último caractere da classe (exemplo `[a-z0-9-]+`)

Comment: @Sanção O rubular (Ruby) reclamou do seu primeiro exemplo, mas o regex101 (JavaScript) e o Python aceitaram bem. Acho que varia com a implementação. Na dúvida, eu continuaria escapando os colchetes. O hífen está ok em todos os casos, e também não precisa escapar se for o primeiro, ou se estiver entre dois intervalos (ex.: em `[a-z-A-Z]` o hífen entre `z` e `A` é um hífen mesmo).

Answer (score 0):

Possuem significados diferentes `.` pode ser qualquer caracter, já `\.` é entendido como o caracter ponto.
**Mas você deve observar o contexto da expressão**, nesse caso ela está concatenando os intervalos de a-z,A-Z,0-9 e também aceita o caracter ponto.